# Adding second story living space in an existing truss attic

Tags: truss

We have a ranch home with a bonus attic room upstairs with trusses on either side of the space. How possible is it to expand out on the truss area adding additional living space? Looking to potentially add bedroom /bathroom which I know would require plumbing all of that but just structurally?

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the space where the photographer was standing, or the space beyond the stud wall, adjacent to the window?

Answer (score 2):

Trusses are engineered to strict specifications.  You cannot modify, ( cut a section out, remove a brace.) without a new engineering plan.

It would be wise to have blueprints done and an engineer to sign off on the structural plans for the framing to achieve what you want.

You may find it is more cost effective to have the roof removed and all new framing done.

In any case this is something a structural engineer must sign off on.